# copy part of string from one column into another

Tags: sql, syntax

I've got a column with some string data that somewhere has 'T##' (## being a two digit number) I want to copy this into another column, how do I do that?

something like this: 
`abc-T03-def` -> `03`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Microsoft SQL Server:

```
update YourTable
    set NewColumn = substring(OldColumn, patindex('%T[0-9][0-9]%', OldColumn) + 1, 2)
    where patindex('%T[0-9][0-9]%', OldColumn) <> 0
```